# Function of two variables - how to supress one variable dependency

Tags: variable

I have this equation i would like to solve:

```
e0 = (2 \[Alpha]1g)/((1 - v1g) (c^2 - b^2))
     Integrate[r \[Tau]1[r, t], {r, b, c}] - (2 v1)/E1 A1;
```

Function e0 represent deformation in vertical (z) axis and based on the equation it is dependant on time t and location r.
Alpha1g, Alpha1, v1g,v1,E1 are material properties and are all known. Equation describes a tube with inner diameter b and outer diameter c, as it is shown on the picture.
[image]

A1 is unknown constant which is determined from other equations and it is not the relevant part of the problem.
Tau[r,t] is temperature function in the tube, dependant on radius and time in form:
[image]

where J0 and Y0 are Bessel function. Temperature function is fully defined.
Based on the background of the problem, I know that deformation e0 is a constant and not a function of time. How can i ignore the time component from the definition of equation (code)?

P.S.: Equation for temperature function Tau[r,t]

```
\[Tau]1[r,t]=-346.514 + 
 E^(-1.78154 t) (-14.3594 BesselJ[0, 2091.05 r] + 
    60.4664 BesselY[0, 2091.05 r]) + 
 E^(-7.14322 t) (42.1879 BesselJ[0, 4187.09 r] - 
    11.9601 BesselY[0, 4187.09 r]) + 
 E^(-16.0795 t) (-25.5497 BesselJ[0, 6282.05 r] - 
    25.0613 BesselY[0, 6282.05 r]) + 
 E^(-28.5902 t) (-7.80375 BesselJ[0, 8376.73 r] + 
    29.991 BesselY[0, 8376.73 r]) + 
 E^(-44.6755 t) (26.7297 BesselJ[0, 10471.3 r] - 
    7.32848 BesselY[0, 10471.3 r]) + 
 E^(-64.3353 t) (-17.9762 BesselJ[0, 12565.8 r] - 
    17.8034 BesselY[0, 12565.8 r]) + 
 E^(-87.5695 t) (-5.96861 BesselJ[0, 14660.3 r] + 
    22.6498 BesselY[0, 14660.3 r]) + 
 E^(-114.378 t) (21.1427 BesselJ[0, 16754.7 r] - 
    5.74734 BesselY[0, 16754.7 r]) + 
 E^(-144.762 t) (-14.6534 BesselJ[0, 18849.2 r] - 
    14.5594 BesselY[0, 18849.2 r]) + 
 E^(-178.719 t) (-5.01706 BesselJ[0, 20943.6 r] + 
    18.9434 BesselY[0, 20943.6 r]) + 
 E^(-216.252 t) (18.035 BesselJ[0, 23038. r] - 
    4.88343 BesselY[0, 23038. r]) + 
 E^(-257.359 t) (-12.6799 BesselJ[0, 25132.5 r] - 
    12.6188 BesselY[0, 25132.5 r]) + 
 E^(-302.04 t) (-4.41131 BesselJ[0, 27226.9 r] + 
    16.6113 BesselY[0, 27226.9 r]) + 
 E^(-350.296 t) (15.9886 BesselJ[0, 29321.3 r] - 
    4.31963 BesselY[0, 29321.3 r]) + 
 E^(-402.126 t) (-11.3357 BesselJ[0, 31415.7 r] - 
    11.292 BesselY[0, 31415.7 r]) + 
 E^(-457.531 t) (-3.98254 BesselJ[0, 33510.1 r] + 
    14.9715 BesselY[0, 33510.1 r]) + 
 E^(-516.51 t) (14.5108 BesselJ[0, 35604.5 r] - 
    3.91468 BesselY[0, 35604.5 r]) + 
 E^(-579.064 t) (-10.3447 BesselJ[0, 37698.9 r] - 
    10.3114 BesselY[0, 37698.9 r]) + 
 E^(-645.192 t) (-3.65854 BesselJ[0, 39793.3 r] + 
    13.7377 BesselY[0, 39793.3 r]) - 67.2882 Log[r]
```

Comment: Please express your function, tau, as code I can copy and paste into Mathematica.

Comment: I added the code to post (actual temperature function is an aproximation with 19 elements, because bessel functions (and their combination is not periodical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want but if you define your equation as a function it can be integrated.

```
ClearAll[\[Tau]1]; \[Tau]1[r_, t_] := -346.514 + 
  E^(-1.78154 t) (-14.3594 BesselJ[0, 2091.05 r] + 
     60.4664 BesselY[0, 2091.05 r]) + 
  E^(-7.14322 t) (42.1879 BesselJ[0, 4187.09 r] - 
     11.9601 BesselY[0, 4187.09 r]) + 
  E^(-16.0795 t) (-25.5497 BesselJ[0, 6282.05 r] - 
     25.0613 BesselY[0, 6282.05 r]) + 
  E^(-28.5902 t) (-7.80375 BesselJ[0, 8376.73 r] + 
     29.991 BesselY[0, 8376.73 r]) + 
  E^(-44.6755 t) (26.7297 BesselJ[0, 10471.3 r] - 
     7.32848 BesselY[0, 10471.3 r]) + 
  E^(-64.3353 t) (-17.9762 BesselJ[0, 12565.8 r] - 
     17.8034 BesselY[0, 12565.8 r]) + 
  E^(-87.5695 t) (-5.96861 BesselJ[0, 14660.3 r] + 
     22.6498 BesselY[0, 14660.3 r]) + 
  E^(-114.378 t) (21.1427 BesselJ[0, 16754.7 r] - 
     5.74734 BesselY[0, 16754.7 r]) + 
  E^(-144.762 t) (-14.6534 BesselJ[0, 18849.2 r] - 
     14.5594 BesselY[0, 18849.2 r]) + 
  E^(-178.719 t) (-5.01706 BesselJ[0, 20943.6 r] + 
     18.9434 BesselY[0, 20943.6 r]) + 
  E^(-216.252 t) (18.035 BesselJ[0, 23038. r] - 
     4.88343 BesselY[0, 23038. r]) + 
  E^(-257.359 t) (-12.6799 BesselJ[0, 25132.5 r] - 
     12.6188 BesselY[0, 25132.5 r]) + 
  E^(-302.04 t) (-4.41131 BesselJ[0, 27226.9 r] + 
     16.6113 BesselY[0, 27226.9 r]) + 
  E^(-350.296 t) (15.9886 BesselJ[0, 29321.3 r] - 
     4.31963 BesselY[0, 29321.3 r]) + 
  E^(-402.126 t) (-11.3357 BesselJ[0, 31415.7 r] - 
     11.292 BesselY[0, 31415.7 r]) + 
  E^(-457.531 t) (-3.98254 BesselJ[0, 33510.1 r] + 
     14.9715 BesselY[0, 33510.1 r]) + 
  E^(-516.51 t) (14.5108 BesselJ[0, 35604.5 r] - 
     3.91468 BesselY[0, 35604.5 r]) + 
  E^(-579.064 t) (-10.3447 BesselJ[0, 37698.9 r] - 
     10.3114 BesselY[0, 37698.9 r]) + 
  E^(-645.192 t) (-3.65854 BesselJ[0, 39793.3 r] + 
     13.7377 BesselY[0, 39793.3 r]) - 67.2882 Log[r]
```

Then

```
int = Integrate[\[Tau]1[r, t], r]
```

Gives a long answer in terms of r and t. If you want the definite integral then you can do

```
fun = (int /. r -> c) - (int /. r -> b)
```

I did try to put the limits of integration into the integration but it took too long.

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, it does. I actually figured it a while ago, that mathematica automatically solves this type of integration the correct way - it integrates only the defined variable.

Comment: Could you help me with this problem?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271964/how-to-correctly-define-solve-for-two-variable-function

Comment: The correct approach is to close this problem by accepting my solutions. I will look at your new problem.